# How can I find open-cv camera calibration constant in python , OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (nimages > 0) in cv::calibrateCamera

Tags: python, opencv, camera-calibration, chessboard.js

I want to find camera calibration constant with below code. However, I had some error message which I don't know. please help me.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import glob[enter image description here][1]

# termination criteria
criteria = (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS + cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER, 30, 0.001)

# 7*7 chess board, prepare object points, like (0,0,0), (1,0,0), (2,0,0) ....,(6,5,0)
object_point = np.zeros((7*7, 3), np.float32)
object_point[:, :2] = np.mgrid[0:7, 0:7].T.reshape(-1, 2)

# 3d point in real world space
object_points = []
# 2d points in image plane
image_points = []
h, w = 0, 0

images = glob.glob('chess board/*.jpg')

for file_name in images:
    image = cv2.imread(file_name)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    h, w = gray.shape[:2]

    # find chess board corners
    ret, corners = cv2.findChessboardCorners(gray, (7, 7), None)

    # add object points, image points
    if ret:
        object_points.append(object_point)
        cv2.cornerSubPix(gray, corners, (11, 11), (-1, -1), criteria)
        image_points.append(corners)

        # draw and display the corners
        cv2.drawChessboardCorners(image, (7, 7), corners, ret)
        cv2.imshow('image', image)
        cv2.waitKey(500)

# calibration
retval, cameraMatrix, distCoeffs, rvecs, tvecs = cv2.calibrateCamera(object_points, image_points, (w, h), None, None)

print "camera matrix:\n", cameraMatrix

# pi camera intrinsic parameters
ay = cameraMatrix[1, 1]
u0 = cameraMatrix[0, 2]
v0 = cameraMatrix[1, 2]
print "Ay:", ay
print "u0:", u0
print "v0:", v0

cv2.destroyAllWindows()ode here
```

This is the error message I get:

> C:\Python27\python.exe "C:/Users/MOMO/PycharmProjects/test/training image/picam_calibration.py"
>   OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (nimages > 0) in cv::calibrateCamera, file ........\opencv\modules\calib3d\src\calibration.cpp, line 3415
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:/Users/MOMO/PycharmProjects/test/training image/picam_calibration.py", line 40, in 
>       retval, cameraMatrix, distCoeffs, rvecs, tvecs = cv2.calibrateCamera(object_points, image_points, (w, h), None, None)
>   cv2.error: ........\opencv\modules\calib3d\src\calibration.cpp:3415: error: (-215) nimages > 0 in function cv::calibrateCamera

Answer (score 0):

You should check that the corner size you pass to the function findChessboardCorner is correct, (7, 7) in your code.

Does this match you checker board pattern ?